# Zurb Foundation Tabs broken after styling

Tags: css, tabs, zurb-foundation

Here's the html.erb page:

```
<div class="tabs-content">
  <div class="content active" id="panel1">
    <h2>Day 2</h2>
    <p>Welcome back!!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel2">
    <p>A <strong>commitment</strong> is when you promise to do something!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel3">
    <p>You have to verify you kept your commitment! You can verifiy by checking in to a location or having a friend act as your referee.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel4">
    <p>Be sure to fulfill your commitment!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-8 columns small-centered">
    <dl class="tabs" data-tab>
      <div class="small-12 columns small-centered">
        <dd class="active"><a href="#panel1"> </a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#panel2"> </a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#panel3"> </a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#panel4"> </a></dd>
      </div>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then I've also added some styling but I don't see why that would prevent the links from hitting individual anchors:

```
.tabs dd > a {
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px !important;
}

.tabs dd{
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius:50%;
}

dl.tabs {
    margin: 0px !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Does this have something to do with the way parent and child elements interact? I'm pretty sure it stopped working when I started putting the dd elements in a div.

But the dots need to be centered. Is there a better way of doing this?

I've examined the Foundation docs but found nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to center the tabs within a column. By default Foundation adds a ***float: left;*** to the element.

Just add the following to your **.tabs dd** CSS.

```
.tabs dd {
        margin: 5px;
        border-radius:50%;
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
}
```

Working example: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/defonic/uf3oaqj9/)